# Why does lazy matching not work in this regex?

Tags: python, regex

Regex: `^(.*?)world(.*?)gamer(.*?)$`

String:

```
fdsfsa
test abc xyz
hello world  ql
te:mlno1
random abc text test 123 890 lll
final line
hu8h
abc
gfdsgfh abc gamer jf123
abc djfkfl
kjdk
```

The goal is to find the full lines containing "world" and "gamer", and all lines in between. The groups aren't necessary, it's just for readability. Using re.M and re.DOTALL in python.

Whether or not the first `.*` is lazy, it still matches the first three lines onward, instead of the only the third line onwards.

Testable here: https://regex101.com/r/5UIBB9/4
But I've verified it in python3 as well.

The problem is solvable with `^([^\n]*?)world(.*?)gamer(.*?)$`, but I want to understand why the `.*?` solution doesn't work. It's killing me...

Thanks!

Comment: Just `.*` will start matching at the beginning of the input string.  Your fix is one way to workaround this problem.

Comment: the `.` character does NOT match newlines

Comment: @Aggragoth It does with `re.DOTALL`

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, but not by default

Comment: @Aggragoth OP is using `re.DOTALL`, though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh, my bad. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.DOTALL` means that a dot matches a newline, so the pattern `^(.*?)world` will initially try to match starting from the first character of the string. This match eventually succeeds due to the DOTALL, so the engine never advances past the first character, so the entire initial part of the string gets included as part of the match.

It's not a matter of lazyness or greedyness - the engine will only advance a character if it finds that a match at the given position is impossible.

Comment: But the point of `.*?` is to consume as little as possible while still providing a valid match, right? Why wouldn't it advance to the start of the third line?

is this just a quirk of the regex engine that I should learn to consider?

Answer (score 2):

What about using something like the following, which doesn't use `re.DOTALL`:

```
^.*(world)(?:.|\n)+?(gamer).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/5UIBB9/7

What this does is gets a line that has the word `world` in it and then gets everything until the first occurrence (lazy) of the word `gamer` in it and grabs the rest of that line as well. Would that work for you?

Otherwise `re.DOTALL` will start, not at the start of the line with the word `world` on it (unless you used something like a negative lookbehind on that line), but at the first character of the string.

If you wanted to use `re.DOTALL` and prevent this behavior at the start and end of the string you'd need to negative the `\n`, but between `world` and `gamer` you could use `.` (as we want it to span multiple lines, leading to:

```
[^\n]*world.*gamer[^\n]*
```

Notice in this case laziness doesn't matter much -- it would matter only if there were multiple occurrences of the word `gamer` and we wanted to know if we wanted to stop at the first or the last occurrence.

Comment: `[\s\S]+?` is much more efficient than `(?:.|\n)+?` that should allways be avoid.

Comment: I do like this solution more than mine.

Comment: @Toto -- thanks, I'm actually going to ask another question as to why that is so.